# Robocopy Error on local path?

Tags: windows, batch, robocopy

When I run the file, it errors out and says "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. 
My file is just one line for now to test and goes like this:

```
@echo off
robocopy "C:\FTPServer\...\...\" "C:\FTPServer\local\...\" /XA:H /REG > #C:\FTPserver\...\...\Logs\Log-%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%.log
```

... is just to mask directory since they contain information.

My supervisor said it based on the way im logging and when we ran without my log it worked. What would be a better way to log it ?

Comment: Trying to use /log:test.txt gives same error

Comment: Why do you have `#C:` instead of `C:`?

Comment: also, remove the trailing `\ ` from your robocopy folders

Comment: @harrymc that is commented out for now. Even uncommented it generates same

Comment: @mael' tried as well. Current works in terms of robocopy, mostly log errors now. 

robocopy "C:\FTPServer\...\Folder" "C:\FTPServer\local\folder" Works

Comment: `#` is not a comment character, so `#C:` is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try structuring it like this:

```
@echo off

set "src=C:\FTPServer\...\...\Source"
set "des=C:\FTPServer\...\...\Destination"
set "log=C:\FTPServer\...\...\Logs"

robocopy "%src%" "%des%" /XA:H /REG /log:"%log%\Log-%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%.log"
```

The main differences being: the removal of the trailing `\`in the robocopy paths, using the `/log` option instead of piping it into a log file, and putting the log path in double quotes so you don't run into issues with spaces or other weird stuff. I used variables so it would fit easier in the block window, though I do tend to recommend them any time you're dealing with long paths.

Comment: This works flawlessly beside that logs are empty and prompt for which application to open with?

Comment: Try replacing `.log` with `.txt` (I always use .txt) - otherwise you should be able to open .logs with Notepad or whatever text editor you prefer.

Comment: tried the .txt ending. still prompts and is empty when selected notepad :/

Comment: what are you actually trying to robocopy? the entire source folder? is the robocopy working and it just isn't putting anything into the log? I believe you can get rid of `/REG` since you don't have `/r:n` or `/w:n` specified. try putting a new file in your source folder and running it to see if the log catches the new file. also, make sure you didn't leave the `>` in your robocopy line.